# How to update multiple columns at once in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I looked up several ways to update multiple columns via SELECT but still unable to get it to work. This is what I tried:

```
delimiter @@
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_sales 
AFTER INSERT ON orders
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE sales 
SET (userid, productid, transaction, price, quarter) =
SELECT userid, productid, COUNT(productid) AS transaction, SUM(total_P) AS price,
       case when (month(date)) >=3 and (month(date)) <=5 then 'Spring' 
            when (month(date)) >=6 and (month(date)) <=8 then 'Summer'
            when (month(date)) >=9 and (month(date)) <=11 then 'Fall' 
            else 'Winter'
            end AS quarter  
FROM orders     
GROUP BY userid, productid, quarter
END@@
delimiter;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` new values?  Is there any relationship between the tables orders and sales?

Comment: I want to update. Yes, the sales table counts how many orders of a particular product that the same user placed in different quarter.

Comment: Any relationship between these tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred way of doing something like this is to do an INSERT query, making sure that each insertion has a primary key that is already being used. Then I add `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, go through all the fields in the form `` `column`=VALUES(`column`) `` and it's good to go. This usually works best with foreign keys in place.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you said? My sales table has 2 foreign keys userid and productid.

When the userid, productid, and quarter of order is not already in sales, then I want to insert a new row to sales. If they already exist, I want to update transaction to transaction+1 and update the total price.

Answer (score 3):

I have tested your query without any sample data, but this solution could set you on the right track.  I used `VIEW` to overcome the `GROUP BY` restriction while using `UPDATE` on multiple tables:

```
CREATE VIEW orders_view AS
     SELECT userid, 
            productid, 
            COUNT(productid) AS 'transaction', 
            SUM(total_P) AS price,
            CASE 
       WHEN (MONTH(o.date)) >=3 AND (MONTH(o.date)) <=5 THEN 'Spring' 
       WHEN (MONTH(o.date)) >=6 AND (MONTH(o.date)) <=8 THEN 'Summer'
       WHEN (MONTH(o.date)) >=9 AND (MONTH(o.date)) <=11 THEN 'Fall'
               ELSE 'Winter'
            END AS quarter    
       FROM orders     
   GROUP BY userid, productid, quarter;

     UPDATE sales s, orders_view o
        SET s.userid = o.userid,
            s.productid = o.productid,
            s.`transaction` = o.`transaction`,
            s.price = o.price,
            s.quarter = o.quarter
      WHERE s.userid = o.userid;
```

Please note that I haven't tested it with real data.

More information:

- MySQL Reference Manual: [`UPDATE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)